# Navigating parent page from iframe in Backbone js

Tags: iframe, backbone.js

In iframe (which is my sidebar) I have some links which when clicked, I want to change the parent page as per user selection. If I had just used href to navigate then I would have done it easily using

```
window.parent.location.href
```

but I'm using App.navigate instead of href for navigation. My code look like this

```
  return App.navigate("exercise/" + numberSelected , {
    trigger: true,
    replace: false
  });
```

I want similar alternative like window.parent.location using App.navigate.

Answer (score 0):

Was just playing around in console and got the answer.

```
return window.parent.App.navigate("exercise/" + numberSelected , {
    trigger: true,
    replace: false
  });
```